# How to count the occurrences of each value of a specific field using PIG?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

The data set is in the form: `FIELD_A--FIELD_B`

Example:

```
XYZ--1
XYZ--2        
XYZ--8        
ABC--4        
ABC--3        
PQR--5
```

Expected output:

```
XYZ-3
ABC-2
PQR-1
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

```
data = LOAD 'dataset' USING PigStorage('--');
field1 = FOREACH data GENERATE $0;
grouped = GROUP field1 BY $0;
count = FOREACH grouped GENERATE COUNT(field1);
```

I don't see why you need the field B, just discard it in the beginning.

Comment: By editing the question, I ruined your answer, but I hope it's ok now with this edit

Comment: thank u :) but job is not getting executed !! no errors are shown though.it is showing "job failed"

Comment: i am not getting the count of all values...i'm getting d count of only first value..plzz do help me out